# SocketException occurred An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ErrorCode=10054

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have been stuck for few days on this issue already. I know the basics of wcf. Managing an existing code and ran into this problem.I have been hosting the application in several of my clients without any issues and the wcf client site has been able to communicate with the service except this wcf service  has been a non-starter.

This is a IIS hosted wcf service. We have a CA issued certificate. I am able to verify the certificate at client so believe that it imported properly imported under Trusted Publishers of mmc.

The wcf client application is able to instantiate the wcf object. But when I call a simple function that returns just "true" (to confirm that wcfobject is reachable) it throws the exception.

```
        EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(practiceUrl),
                                            EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(dnsIdentity));
        DataServiceClient wcfObject = new DataServiceClient("wsHttpEndPoint", myEndpointAdd);

        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        ((WSHttpBinding)wcfObject.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;

        wcfObject.IsClientRunning(); //service should return true if all goes well
```

The client has opened the firewall to my machine IP and from my browser I am able to see the landing page of the service installed in client.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingSettings" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I also installed the service trace viewer, But that is not showing any errors.
[image: TraceLog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of slow internet connection and it was timing out at the initial handshake process during authenticating the certificate.